# RadListView doesn't display items

Tags: angular2-nativescript, radlistview

I am having much difficulties implementing RadListView in my application. According to documentation the ListView accepts items as an ObservableArray, but regardless of whether that or plain array is used, items are not being displayed. I prepared a sample app in the Playground

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=39xE2X&v=11

Component is like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { GestureTypes, PanGestureEventData, TouchGestureEventData } from "tns-core-modules/ui/gestures";
import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public gridData = []; //new ObservableArray<any>();

    constructor(
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
        this.feedTestData();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {

    }

    public detectChanges() {
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }

    private feedTestData() {


        let data = [
             {
                 description: 'line 1',
             },
             {
                 description: 'line 2',
             },
        ];

        this.gridData.splice(0, 0, data);
    }

}
```

and template like this:

```
<GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <RadListView [items]="gridData">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Label [text]="description"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

What's perplexing me even more is that in my real application RadListView displays something, but does it on its own, completely ignoring my template. I can literally leave nothing inside RadListView, but it would still display items
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your playground and it is working now.
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=39xE2X&v=12

You were trying to access the description in ng-template while it should be item.description

`<Label [text]="item.description"></Label>`

Also for the testing purpose, I am creating an Onservable array from your data. `this.gridData = new ObservableArray(data);` in your feedTestData function.